# How to get the difference (data) in data between two independent tables - using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The data in T1 and T2 is present for multiple rows on multiple dates, i wrote these sql to get below data sets.

Table T1 is result of below sql:

```
select SYS_ID, SYS_NM 
FROM T1
WHERE dt = '30-NOV-2015' 
group by SYS_ID, SYS_NM
order by 1,2; 

T1  
    SYS_ID  SYS_NM
    4       MPC
    4       MHL
    6       FR
    8       BECD
    8       BCD
    8       CL
    8       FHLB
    8       JRD
```

---

Table T2 is result of below sql

```
Select SYS_ID, SYS_NM FROM T2
WHERE dt = '30-NOV-2015' 
and SYS_CD IN ('R103')
group by SYS_ID, SYS_NM
order by 1,2;

T2  
    SYS_ID  SYS_NM
    8       BECD
    8       BCD
    8       FHLB
```

Now i need to get the data from `T1` that are not present in `T2`.
I tried doing this in two ways, but I'm not getting the expected results.

```
Method 1:

    select A.SYS_ID, A.SYS_NM
    FROM T1 A
    WHERE not exists 
    (
    select B.SYS_ID, B.SYS_NM
    FROM T2 B
    WHERE A.SYS_ID = B.SYS_ID
    and A.SYS_NM = B.SYS_NM
    group by 1, 2
    )
    group by 1,2
    order by 1,2;
```

Method 2:

```
Select A.SYS_ID, A.SYS_NM FROM T1 A
LEFT JOIN T2 B
   ON A.SYS_ID = B.SYS_ID
   group by A.SYS_ID, A.SYS_NM
order by 1,2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM T2 
 WHERE T2.SYS_ID = T1.SYS_ID 
 AND T2.SYS_NM = T1.SYS_NM) 
 order by 1, 2;
```

UPDATE:
I am guessing that you are seeing duplicate rows in the result.  If so, adding "DISTINCT" will correct that.

I also noticed the answer that I previously recommended doesn't have both columns in the JOIN clause.  Here is the complete solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.SYS_ID, A.SYS_NM 
FROM T1 A 
LEFT JOIN T2 B ON A.SYS_ID = B.SYS_ID AND A.SYS_NM=B.SYS_NM
WHERE B.SYS_ID IS NULL 
GROUP BY A.SYS_ID, A.SYS_NM;
```

Comment: Is it different than method 1 above?

Comment: @ASH  You don't want to group the data.  You want each data row to be compared between T1 and T2.

Comment: Thanks Silver, i have added more detail to my question based on what i understood from your answer.

Comment: @ASH  Do you want the results to include all of the columns in the tables or just SYS_ID and SYS_NM ?

Comment: just the these two columns as i need to figure out what all SYS_ID and SYS_NM are not in T2

Comment: @ASH  I believe Parfait's answer will work.  Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: @ASH  If my answer was helpful, please mark it as the answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could go for the usual equality comparison between all columns of both tables, inverted with the "not" operator.

*What I mean, is, just go for a `SELECT` for the case that you want to retrieve rows that are same, inverted with a "not" operator.*

Answer (score 0):

Continue with Method 2 but add the `IS NULL` condition:

ONLY T1 SYS_ID RECORDS (NOT IN T2)

```
SELECT A.SYS_ID, A.SYS_NM 
FROM T1 A 
LEFT JOIN T2 B ON A.SYS_ID = B.SYS_ID
WHERE B.SYS_ID IS NULL 
GROUP BY A.SYS_ID, A.SYS_NM;
```

ONLY T2 SYS_ID RECORDS (NOT IN T1)

```
SELECT B.SYS_ID, B.SYS_NM 
FROM T1 A 
RIGHT JOIN T2 B ON A.SYS_ID = B.SYS_ID
WHERE A.SYS_ID IS NULL 
GROUP BY B.SYS_ID, B.SYS_NM;
```

Comment: Thanks Parfait.. but i am not getting the correct result. the sql did not return any record.

Comment: Is `SYS_ID` a unique identifier? In other words, do the same `SYS_NM` **not** share same ids? If id is a unique key, then use `SYS_NM` instead of `SYS_ID` in `JOIN ON` clause.